# What does it take to build an effective Faraday cage at bedroom-scale?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radio-frequency

I want to block all EMF transmissions -- tv, radio, cell phone, wifi etcetera. I'm not trying to protect myself from an atmospheric detonation or solar storms, just the RF / EM "noise" of modern life.

I envision solid conductive foil / sheets on all walls, with "shutters" over the windows and door, and maybe flaps over receptacles / smoke detectors / thermostats / etcetera. I understand that so long as no line-of-sight gaps exist, gaps are acceptable. In other words, object "X" is protected in both of the following diagrams, as long as all "|" elements form a single circuit:

```
+---
|
|  -----+
|       |
|    X  |
|       |
|  -----+
|
+---

+---    |    |
|       |    |
|  -----+    |
|            |
|    X       |
|            |
|  -----+    |
|       |    |
+---    |    |
```

**Questions**

- Am I / are we in the correct forum for this sort of question?
- Do I have the right basic understanding of a Faraday cage?
- Are "conductive paints" and "conductive fabrics" worth evaluation?
- If I need a solid conductor, does the thickness of material matter? E.g., is copper
  foil as effective as copper sheet?
- Is connecting to ground required?
- If yes, is connecting to the house ground sufficient?

Again, please let me know if this should be posted elsewhere, or if there's introductory material I should review before my next post.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends, how much attenuation is required? Your "line of sight" understanding is incorrect. EM waves reflect from conductors!

Comment: see https://hackaday.com/2018/09/26/building-a-hardware-store-faraday-cage/.  “ The rule of thumb for a Faraday cage is that the openings should be no larger than 1/10th of the wavelength” to be blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked in a Faraday cage when I did experiments with the setup for NMR (nuclear magnetic resonance). It was completely enclosed in copper mesh, soldered together in corners. I am pretty certain that it was grounded, but that was only for electrical safety.

This was way before smartphones, so I do not really know how if it was impossible to connect from the inside, but I would assume that. The mesh of a micro wave oven is also good enough to keep the 2.45 GHz inside. (However, I just tested: find-my-phone works even when my phone is in the microwave oven.)

Advantage of a mesh is that it costs less copper and that the visible EM radiation can pass through. (Or maybe that is a disadvantage in your case, I don't know.)

Comment: I would think that metal screening that can be purchased in large panels for screening a patio would do. You would need an overlap for electrical contact, and grounding might be needed. You might try small scale testing.